# How to select the type of file when using SaveImage()

Tags: save, export, dm-script

I have realize that the SaveImage() command uses the last the last type of format that has been selected during normal DM operation. I assume that this option is selected somewhere in the GobalInfo tags. Please, could someone tell me which tag I have to modify to select dm4 format when I use SaveImage()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'SaveImage()' is just a convenience wrapper.  It is generally not the
>   *Image* which is saved to file, but an *ImageDocument* which can contain one ore more images. The latest DigitalMicograph help
>   documentation is more detailed about loading/saving than previous
>   ones, so I'm just copy-pasting the according passages below:

[image: Saving Info]

[image: Saving Images]

[image: ImageDocument Saving]

For example to store the front-most displayed image(document) as DM images, you may use:

```
string name = "C:\\TempImg"
string handler = "Gatan 3 Format"
ImageDocument doc = GetFrontImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( handler, name )
```

And you can always get the *ImageDocument* from any image, using:

```
string handler = "Gatan 3 Format"
image img := RealImage("Test - not yet shown", 4, 100, 100 )
string name = "C:\\" + img.GetName()
ImageDocument doc = img.ImageGetOrCreateImageDocument()
doc.ImageDocumentSaveToFile( handler, name )
```